# I need the Digital persona U.are.U 4500 Client to Ubuntu or Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, digital-persona-sdk

I have a development using this documentation "https://hidglobal.github.io/digitalpersona-devices/tutorial.html" but the client does not work for me because it is a client for Windows "https://www.crossmatch.com/AltusFiles/ AltusLite/digitalPersonaClient.Setup64.exe" does anyone know how to do the same thing that the client does but for linux or a driver but for ubuntu?

Digital persona  U.are.U 4500 Client to Ubuntu or Linux

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it, I leave you my git repository

https://github.com/JuanNieto99/instalacion-sdk-digitalpersona.git

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).